# How to implement a pop-up window when hovering on a URL link

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, quicklook, nspanel

I'm relatively new to Cocoa application. In my application (MacOS), I already mark the text if it contains image url link. What I'm trying doing now is that when the mouse hover (without clicking) on the link, the application will open an NSPanel (sorry, if it's inaccurate) and show the content of the image url. Also, the panel/window will be closed automatically when mouse move out of the text.

I've tried something such as "floating window/panel/quicklook", but the search result isn't close to what I want. Could anyone please give me some keywords so I can try to find the solution by myself? Thank you.

Comment: A floating pop-up window is a `NSPopover`. You probably tried "cocoa quicklook panel" but if `QLPreviewPanel` isn't close to what you want, can you explain why?

Comment: subclass the Panel then.